# How to associate, disassociate objects using has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm still very new to rails programming, and it's my first question at stackoverflow.

I have models Group and Product like so:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end

class Products < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :Group
end
```

Now, I have some data filled with multiple products in multiple groups. What should I do when I want to move one of the product from one group to another?

-Should I be using has_many :through relationship (and is that the only suggested way)? (Because I think that dealing with 3 tables are more complicated and calculation-intensive than just 2 tables.)

-Is there a preferred way for doing this?

Here's the things I've tried:
-Setting nil to group_id in products and updating it to remove the association which worked. I'm just not sure if this is the right way of disassociating an object.

-I tried creating a custom function in groups_controller.rb like below. (and I know that this may not be the right way of doing it, but I'm a bit desperate)

in the /view/groups/show.html.erb I have

```
  <% form_tag group_add_reference_path(@group.id), :method => 'put' do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'params[group_id]', "#{@group.id}" %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= collection_select('params', 'product_id', Product.where(:group_id => nil), :id, :name) %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= submit_tag "assign", :name => nil %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

and in the groups_controller.rb I have

```
  def add_reference
    @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
    @product = Product.find(params["product_id"])
    @group.products << @product
  end
```

-I've read Detailed Association Reference chapter of [association_basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) in railsguides, and since it has collection<<(object) function added, I though I should be able to do something close to above. (which is not working because @product seems to be nil for some reason, and even if I set it to a valid ID and hardcode it, it fails on the line after that)

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have answered this yourself :

If they can only be associate with *one* group at a time, do this :

```
def add_reference
  @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  @product.update_attribute("group_id", params[:group_id])
end
```

Comment: I forgot to write that I've tried this. In this case, it says 'update_attribute' method not found. Therefore, I added 'accept_nested_attributes_for :products' in Group model. Still, it didn't work. Am I even allowed to call update_attribute on Product from Group controller?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Your comment helped me try to figure out why I wasn't getting the @product.

Answer (score 0):

Moving a product from one group to another requires just one simple thing: Changing the product's `group_id` to "point" to the new group, that is, the `group_id` column should contain the new group's id after the change. Mr Trip's answer shows you the actual code.

Comment: So you are suggesting that my configuration (using has_many products, belongs_to group) is not allowed to make a product with a nil group_id?

Answer (score 0):

I found out why it wasn't working.

in the above code that I wrote, the collection_select returns a hash itself.
therefore:

```
@product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
```

doesn't work (because all request parameters also come in a hash).

What I had to do was to access the recursive hash (not sure if the word is correct) like:

```
@product = Product.find(params[:params][:product_id])
```

Or, use where instead of find like:

```
@product = Product.where(params[:params]).limit(1)
```

and it works!!

Thank you for all of the comments. That kept me working on it.